# Sum time in Excel to show a big number of days

Tags: excel, datetime, time, excel-formula, sum

I have cells with duration, specified as hours:minutes:seconds.

- 1726:48:00
- 410:10:00
- 599:20:00

The first line means 1726 hours, 48 minutes and 00 seconds
The second line means 410 hours, 10 minutes and 00 seconds
The third line means 599 hours, 10 minutes and 00 seconds

How do I sum these times in Excel, to get a breakdown in days, hours, minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that might be impossible by changing the cell format.

If your number is in `A1`, you could use one of these 2 formulas:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)&TEXT(A1," hh:mm:ss")
=INT(A1)&TEXT(A1," hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

I also tried `=TEXT(A1,"0")&TEXT(A1," hh:mm:ss")`, but `TEXT(A1,"0")` sometimes does roundup which is not welcome.

The drawback of those formulas is that they return `text`. So you'll not be able to use the results in further calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is to add a `range` of `cells` containing values called *“duration”*, which are expressed in `Date and Time Serial Numbers` and to display the result, currently *formatted* as `[h]:mm:ss`, in *days, hours, minutes and seconds*, (a kind of format `[d] hh:mm:ss` which is not allowed by the Excel application as already explained by *ZygD*). *ZygD* also proposed to use a formula to display the desired result as a text which comes with the restriction of further use in other calculations as well explained by *ZygD*:

```
=INT(A1)&TEXT(A1," hh:mm:ss")
```

In case that the total expressed as text needs to be expressed back as a `Date and Time Serial Numbers` I suggested the formula:

```
=SUM(LEFT(B1,-1+SEARCH(" ",B1)),
SUBSTITUTE(B1,LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)),""))
```

Now if this does not satisfy the requirement there is another solution, that allows to add the `Date and Time Serial Numbers` showing the result as *“days, hours, minutes and seconds”* *provided that it’s acceptable to show the result in two separated cells* using the following formulas:

Values with “duration” are placed in the range `C4:C6`,
Totals Days in cell `"C10"`,
Total Hours in cell `"C11"`

Totals Days `=INT(SUM($C$4:$C$6))`

Total Hours `=MOD(SUM($C$4:$C$6),1)`

If the totals are needed for further use just use the standard "SUM" formula to add up both, see cell `C13`

```
=SUM(C10,C11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *"original"* value can be worked backwards from *ZygD's formula* using the following formula:

```
=SUM(LEFT(B1,-1+SEARCH(" ",B1)),
SUBSTITUTE(B1,LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)),""))
```